# Start writing drivers

Tags: ros, actuator, driver, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

we are starting a project and we want to implement new sensors and actuators for our ROS-project.
My task is to provide the e.g. data of an IR sensor or implement I2C-bus.
My first thought was: Poll the sensor and write a publisher.
But I guess you guys are more expirience in such a task, so I want to ask you first.

While I have expirience with ROS already, I have never done such a thing.
Do you have any good idea where to start or any tutorial how I can write a driver in ROS?

Greetz,
tiko

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76981/start-writing-drivers/) by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you interface the I2C bus? Directly from the computer?
If you have no interface yet look at the arduino I2C tutorials:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/SRF08%20Ultrasonic%20Range%20Finder

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) on 2013-09-08**:
Hi davinci,

thanks for the quick answer.
We do it in a similar way, by having the libraries already.

Anyway, I was just concerned about the way to talk with such sensors and actuator.
But as I thought, it is just the straight way by writing a simple publisher.

Thanks!